# Passing value to Component as props in Nextjs

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I am trying to pass editvalues as props to my EditForm component and getting the error editvalues is not defined.

Note:- editvalues is an object

I tried to `console.log(editvalues)` and I am getting them in the console

My `[id].tsx` file

**EDIT**
The editvalues are being passed from my TableComponent,notice the `<EditTwoTone onClick = {() => onEdit(record)}/>` in TableComponent

TableComponent.tsx

```
const TableComponent = ({fetchedData}) => {
  const [dataSource, setDataSource] = useState(fetchedData);
  console.log(fetchedData)
  const columns = [
    {
      title: "Project Name",
      dataIndex: "project_name",
      key: "project_name",
      sorter: (a:String,b:String) => a.project_name.length - b.project_name.length,
    },
    {
      title: "Project Description",
      dataIndex: "project_Description",
      key: "project_Description",
    },
    {
      title: "NameSpace",
      dataIndex: "project_Name_space",
      key: "project_Name_space",
    },
    {
      title: "Action",
      key: "action",
      render: (record: any) => (
        <Space size="large">
          {/* EDIT ICON */}
          <Link href={`/editproject/${record.project_ID}`}>
            <EditTwoTone onClick = {() => onEdit(record)}/>
          </Link>
          {/* DELETE ICON */}
          <DeleteOutlined
            style={{ color: "red" }}
            onClick={() => onDeleteRecord(record)}
          />
        </Space>
      ),
    },
  ];


import MainComponentLayout from "../../components/Layout/MainLayoutComponent"
import EditProject from "../../components/EditProjectForm";



const EditForm = () => {
    return(
        <MainComponentLayout ComponentToRender = {<EditProject editvalues = {editvalues}/>}/>
    )
}
export const onEdit = (editValues) => {
    console.log("on Edit function with values",editValues);
}

export default EditForm
```

Why am I getting Unhandled Runtime Error
ReferenceError: editvalues is not defined

Comment: are you trying to pass the onEdit function as a prop? 

`<EditProject editvalues = {onEdit}/>`

Comment: Because it is not defined. Where have you defined `editvalues` that you have passed to `EditProject`? The `editvalues` inside `onEdit` is not accessible inside `EditForm`.

Comment: <EditProject editvalues = {onEdit(paramsEditValues)}/>

Answer (score -1):

You call a function that need to pass parameter

```
const EditForm = () => {
    return(
        <MainComponentLayout ComponentToRender = {<EditProject editvalues = {onEdit(paramsEditValues)}/>}/>
    )
}
export const onEdit = (editValues) => {
    console.log("on Edit function with values",editValues);
}
```

your function name is `onEdit` and requir `editValues` parameter